# New Spring Data JDK8 Jsr310JpaConverters not working automatically?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use Spring Data JPA 1.8 new jdk date converters.

In my Spring Boot application I've added a config class like:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.class)
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class DataConfig {
}
```

This is how `org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten.Jsr310JpaConverters` suggests how to apply the auto conversion. I also used direct package references like `org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support` and `org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten`.

The problem is the jdk 8 date conversion do not happen resulting in sql exceptions.

However, when I apply the converter manually to in my domain class like:

```
@Convert(converter = Jsr310JpaConverters.LocalDateConverter.class)
private LocalDate birthdate;
```

Then the conversion does work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using Spring Boot can simply add `Jsr310JpaConverters` like below

```java
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = { Application.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class })
@SpringBootApplication
class Application { … }
```

or add `org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten` to the packages to scan.

Comment: Yes `@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {Application.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class})` did the trick. I used @ComponentScan which is not correct.

Comment: Good to mention that you have to explicitly include your Boot's Application.class as otherwise it won't work.