# Multiple datasources with Jsr310JpaConverters not work

Tags: java-8, spring-data-jpa, jsr310

When there is a `LocalDateTime` attribute in `Entity`, serialization fails when using the repository interface query, and when a single data source is working.

When I only use the following configuration in `application.java`, it does not work:

```
@EntityScan (
         BasePackageClasses = {Application.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class}
)
```

When I do not use the above configuration, the `LocalDateTime` property is directly configured with the following configuration, it works:

```
@Convert (converter = Jsr310JpaConverters.LocalDateConverter.class)
```

Can anyone help me?

**Note:** I found a question related to this one, **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241575/new-spring-data-jdk8-jsr310jpaconverters-not-working-automatically)**.