# Is Spring-Boot (still) not working with JSR310Converters for Java 8 LocalDate by default?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Java 8 along with `Spring-Boot 1.5.10.RELEASE`.

I still seem to need `@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = { Application.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class })` in my Application class.

I thought Spring-Boot supports Jsr310/Java8 LocalDate API starting 1.4 (according to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2721)? I am asking this, because in the 4th reply on that issue mentioned above it is mentioned, that using @EntityScan switches off the default behavior. I think

I should not need this - or do I?

Here are the relevant parts of my **pom.xml**:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <!-- <scope>runtime</scope> -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- some other libraries, that do not contain anything hibernate/JPA -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Edgware.SR3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

In my effective POM I do have both `hazelcast-hibernate4` and `hazelcast-hibernate5`. Is this correct? Or is something wrong with my pom.xml?

Related SO-Q&A: [New Spring Data JDK8 Jsr310JpaConverters not working automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241575/new-spring-data-jdk8-jsr310jpaconverters-not-working-automatically)

Note: this question is not related to the jackson-part (JSON) of the JSR310 problem as I did solve it by properly declaring `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310` as a dependency.

**Update:**
According to `mvn depedency:tree` I only use `hibernate-core 5.0.12.Final`, `hibernate-entitymanager 5.0.12.Final` and `hibernate-validator 5.3.6.Final`. All of them are parts of some spring-boot packages.

This leaves me puzzled: if JSR310Convverters for LocalDate were implemented in hibernate 5 - why do I still have to use `@EntityScan`-annotation?

Comment: The support was not added directly in spring since it was being fixed hibernate 5 https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8844. You would need hibernate-java8 dependency to address any issues. And I would suggest you read the comments from philwebb commented on Apr 5, 2016 and holgerstolzenberg commented on Nov 6, 2015 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2763 which will help you get more clarity. Btw, why do you need both hazelcast versions?  hazelcast-hibernate5 should alone be enough.

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi: I will have to dig up the dependency-tree to see where they are coming from. The effective POM view says that both versions have been added (I did **not** intend this as I am writing a simple service with database access, currently using H2DB (without pooling)).

Comment: Okay: it seems the effective POM is showing too many dependencies... according to *"mvn depedency:tree* I **only** use **hibernate-core 5.0.12.Final**, **hibernate-entitymanager 5.0.12.Final** and **hibernate-validator 5.3.6.Final**. All of them are parts of some spring-boot packages. No version 4 AND 5... I will go read the issue you suggested. Thanks so far.

Comment: Any update on this one? I still have to use `@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {Application.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class})` as well

Comment: @PatrikMihalčin I am going to post a reply that currently works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an "okay"-solution for myself. There are 2 aspects to cover in this context:

- JSON-conversion
- JPA-conversion

For JSON-conversion I set this property in the **application.properties** file:

`spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false`

In order to have the **database** (I am using H2) contain TIMESTAMP-type columns with values rather than VARBINARY-type columns with values one cannot read right away nor properly sort, one currently seems to **have to** include:

`@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = { Application.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class })`

I wish it would automatically use those converters since I am on Java 8 anyway, but unfortunately it does not seem to do that.

Please note the following:

> This isn't quite as straightforward as I thought. Using @EntityScan on
>   one of our configuration classes has the unwanted side-effect of
>   switching off the default which is retrieved from
>   AutoConfigurationPackages

*(Comment from [Spring Issue 2721](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2721) by wilkinsona, 13. August, 2015)*

Answer (score 1):

You have to add dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and you won't need to specify `@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {Application.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class})` on your `Application` class anymore